# Log4j2 - RootLogger appender not working

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j2

I have a maven project which uses log4j2 for logging. I want to override the pattern of the RootLogger.

This is my log4j2.properties file:

```
status = debug
name= properties_configuration

# Give directory path where log files should get stored
property.basePath = ./log/

appenders =console, rolling

# ConsoleAppender will print logs on console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout

# Specify the pattern of the logs
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] 
[%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg %xEx %n


# RollingFileAppender will print logs in file which can be rotated based on 
time or size
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName=${basePath}/app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern=${basePath}app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] 
[%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg %xEx %n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

# Rotate log file each day
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
# Delete files older than 30 days
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d


logger.example.name = com.parohia
logger.example.level = debug
logger.example.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
logger.example.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
```

This is my pom.xml file for log4j:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I call my logger like this:

```
      private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PersoaneController.class);
      try{
          .....
      }
      catch(Exception ex){
           logger.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);
      }
```

My configuration has 2 problems. The first is that the root logger does not use my consoleAppender(warning and such appear in the default format) and when logging the error i get only the first line not the entire stack trace).

Comment: It seems your configuration file is not valid like layout pattern is in 2 lines, comments are in 2 lines. By this way, 2nd line is actually getting invalid

Answer (score 0):

If your patterns are actually split up into multiple lines in your properties file as shown in your question:

```
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] 
[%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg %xEx %n

appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] 
[%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg %xEx %n
```

then you need to change them such that the pattern is entirely on a single line:

```
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg %xEx %n

appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg %xEx %n
```

Comment: My pattern is on a single line. I'm sorry if the format appears split on multiple lines.